# Unknown key in Rails association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have the following associations code:

```
has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, :class_name => "Rate",
  :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}
has_many :raters_without_dimension, :through => :rates_without_dimension,
  :source => :rater  

has_one :rate_average_without_dimension, :as => :cacheable,
  :class_name => "RatingCache", 
:dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => nil}


dimensions.each do |dimension|        
  has_many "#{dimension}_rates", :dependent => :destroy, 
    :conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s}, 
    :class_name => "Rate", 
    :as => :rateable

  has_many "#{dimension}_raters", :through => "#{dimension}_rates",
    :source => :rater         

  has_one "#{dimension}_average", :as => :cacheable, :class_name => "RatingCache", 
    :dependent => :destroy, :conditions => {:dimension => dimension.to_s}
end
```

It raises an error:

```
Unknown key: :conditions. Valid keys are: :class_name, :class, :foreign_key, :validate, :autosave, :table_name, :before_add, :after_add, :before_remove, :after_remove, :extend, :primary_key, :dependent, :as, :through, :source, :source_type, :inverse_of, :counter_cache
```

I tried to change the first line into:

```
has_many :rates_without_dimension, :as => :rateable, :class_name => "Rate", :dependent => :destroy,-> { where(:dimension => nil) }
```

But it also raised an error, can you point me to what is wrong with it?

Comment: Edited the question to include the source code from an external site. From [SO help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): "If it is possible to create a live example of the problem that you can link to (for example, on http://sqlfiddle.com/ or http://jsbin.com/) then do so - but also include the code in your question itself. Not everyone can access external sites, and the links may break over time."

Comment: Thanks for your edit and quote :)

Comment: What was the error using the -> notation?

Answer (score 9):

Same problem described here https://teamtreehouse.com/forum/unknown-key-conditions

As I see in examples, lambda with condition should does after association name, because hash without `{}` can be only as last argument.

Try

```
has_many :rates_without_dimension, -> { where(dimension: nil) }, as: :rateable, class_name: "Rate", dependent: :destroy
```

p.s. you can use http://apidock.com/rails/Object/with_options to make it looks nicer